# Updating arrays via user input

Tags: java, arrays, methods, menu, do-while

I have a menu that is navigated with a do-while loop, based off a integer selection. One of the selections is to add a new part to my inventory. When i add the part it works but then i try to display it in the menu option "Display all parts" (selection 4) and the added part isn't there. Why aren't the arrays being displayed with the new values included?

```
  else if(selection == 3){
                System.out.println("--------------Individual Parts--------------");
                System.out.println("ID: " + "\t  Name: " + "\tStock Level: " + "\tUnit Price: ");
                Part p = new Part();
                p.printInv(); ------DOESN'T WORK HERE, AFTER ADDING NEW VALUES------
                System.out.println("");

} else if(selection == 4){
                Part p = new Part();
                System.out.println("Add name for new part"); 
                String n = sc.nextLine();
                p.addNameToInv(n);
                System.out.print("Please allocate ID. The next free ID is: ");
                p.findNextID();
                String n2 = sc.nextLine();
                p.addIDToInv(n2);
                p.printInv(); // -----WORKS HERE-----

            } else if(selection >=5){
                System.out.println("Invalid selection. Please try again.");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
            }

    } while(selection != 0);
```

implementation of the printInv() method

```
public void printInv(){
    for(int i=0; i<invName.length; i++){
        if(invName[i] != null){
            System.out.println(invID[i] + "\t  " + invName[i]
                            + "\t    " + invSL[i] + "\t\t   " + invUP[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the implementation of the `printInv()` function?

Comment: @dansey Did any answer help? You can mark an answer to show others which solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to save the `Part p` created in `if(selection == 4)` to be able to display it later in `if(selection == 3)`.

What you do now in `if(selection == 3)` is:

```
 Part p = new Part(); //you create a new EMPTY part.
 p.printInv(); //works fine, but its your newly created empty part without values.
```

Comment: how would i save the Part p in the if(selection ==4)?

Comment: See @IsuruJ his answer, using an array of listparts or if you only want to keep one, just make a global variable or a class field

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to keep a reference to the instance of the Part you created in 'if(selection == 3)'.

So you can add it to a collection like a ArrayList or map kind of data structure HashMap, which is kept as an instance variable, and then refer to that Part instance, which you created, via this ArrayList / HashMap.

```
public class Menu {

    private ArrayList<Part> listOfParts = new ArrayList<Part>();

    public void partAdditionAndDisplay(int selection) {
        if (selection == 3) {
            Part p = listOfParts.get(index); // some required index / can use a HashMap to refer from a key
            p.printInv();
            System.out.println("");

        } else if (selection == 4) {
            Part p = new Part();
            listOfParts.add(p);
            p.printInv();

        } 
    }
}
```